# Whats wrong with my code snippet?

Tags: c++, code-snippets

```
    int myArray[8];
         for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            myArray [i] = 0;
```

I'm pretty sure it's an out-of-bounds error.
i <= 8 should be i < 8.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You could verify this with just about any array article/tutorial/reference.

Comment: Job interview by any chance?

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Try to improve your question to get more constructive answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating 8 blocks, 0-7 and you are trying to reference myArray[8]

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
                ///^^^
```

index out of bound, array index starts from 0

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I just wanted to make sure I was correct. @tacp

Answer (score 0):

int myArray[8] means you have 8 variables:

myArray[0]

myArray[1]

myArray[2]

myArray[3]

myArray[4]

myArray[5]

myArray[6]

myArray[7]

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: In for loop myArray[8] will be initialized and it is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Then you should say that in your answer.